# How to add new keyboard layouts in Manjaro Fluxbox?

Tags: software-installation, keyboard-layout, manjaro, fluxbox

I want to try Manjaro Fluxbox, and I would say it's my favorite Manjaro to date, except for some quirks like the one that  I don't know --- not only [how to get a keyboard layout indicator / switcher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/234742/32012), but --- **how to add a (second,  third, fourth) keyboard layout** in the first place, which I would try to switch by some command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they need not be added, as they are there already.

As indicated [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Keyboard_Layout), the commands are very simple:

For US English:

```
setxkbmap us
```

For French:

```
setxkbmap fr
```

For Romanian:

```
setxkbmap ro
```

For the same with a variant:

```
setxkbmap ro std_cedilla
```

*A list of all possible keyboard layouts and other parameters can be found in: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst.*