# Switch keyboard layouts with a launcher like Synapse

Tags: keyboard-layout, synapse

There are some light desktops like Openbox and Fluxbox that may [not have a panel applet/switcher for keyboard layouts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/234742/32012). I fact even those that work, [had some problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236343/32012).

In such a case switching keyboard layouts through a program launcher like Synapse would be a good solution.

Is it possible?

Comment: @Ramesh - I have tried to clarify the purpose of the question

Comment: @ EricRenouf - I have tried to clarify the purpose of the question

Comment: @Anthon - I have edited and tried to clarify the purpose of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done by adding the specific keyboard layout command into a `.desktop` file saved in `~/.local/share/applications` along the other desktop files that launchers like Synapse can therefore access.

The keyboard layout command to select a certain layout is like:

```
setxkbmap us intl
```

Change `us` with the desired language and `intl` with variant if necessary.

For French it should be `setxkbmap fr`. Etc. A list of all possible keyboard layouts and other parameters can be found in: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`.

The desktop file should have a form similar to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=US - Keyboard US International dead Keys
Exec=setxkbmap us intl
Icon=path/to/some/icon/file
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Utility;
```

[image]