# Switch keyboard layouts from Plank dock

Tags: keyboard-layout, dock, plank

Can Plank dock be used to switch between keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plank can display folder contents as a stack.

The idea is to create a desktop file for each command to select a given keyboard layout.

The command is something like

> setxkbmap us

or

> setxkbmap us intl

Change `us` with the desired language and `intl` with variant if necessary.

(for example, for French it should be `setxkbmap fr`. A list of all possible keyboard layouts and other parameters can be found in: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`.)

The desktop file should be like so

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keyboard US International dead Keys
Exec=setxkbmap us intl
Icon=path/to/some/icon/file
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Utility;
```

So, create separate such desktop files for each keyboard layout you need and copy all those in a folder (let's say it is called MyKB).

To add the folder to Plank drag-and-drop should work.

If not, go to `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers` (`dock1` may vary depending on the number of docks) and create a new `.dockitem` file with these lines

```
[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///PATH/TO/MyKB
```

[image]